# Is BIP analogous to RFC?

Tags: terminology, bip

It seems that a BIP (Bitcoin Improvement Proposal) is very similar to an RFC (Request for Comments). Can anybody confirm this, or describe major differences in the two approaches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BIP's and RFC's are similar in that they

- debate an implementation in the community in order to improve it, and
- produce documentation that's useful to other coders.

However, they're different in a lot of other ways. This is largely because the two solve different problems: RFC's usually invent new protocols, whereas BIP's amend an existing system.

Other differences:

- An RFC with a specific serial number always refers to a specific version of that document. If the RFC changes (and the change isn't something tiny, like spelling), it is assigned a new number.

  On the other hand, a BIP is expected to go through multiple major revisions in the Draft stage. Changes are instead tracked through version control.
- The [RFC approval process](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2223#section-2) and the [BIP approval process](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0001.mediawiki#BIP_Work_Flow) are different.
- RFC's have *authors*, BIP's have *champions*. This isn't just a difference in terminology. The champion of a BIP needs to convince other people that it's a good idea before it will be accepted, whereas the RFC process is much less restrictive.

See also:

- [Who specified the Bitcoin protocol?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32083/who-specified-the-bitcoin-protocol/32085#32085)
- [How is a BIP accepted?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5640/how-is-a-bip-accepted/18082#18082)